# Neukirch mysterious homomorphism in Abstract Kummer Theory (in his book ANT)

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory, kummer-theory

Someone familiar with Neukirch's terminology can understand this post better. Unfortunately it is so much terminology to just explain it here.

My question is about what is marked in the picture:

Why is this map $\chi_a$ is a homomorphism? I see no apparent reason to have

(Recall that $\alpha^{\sigma-1}=\alpha^{\sigma}\alpha^{-1}$ by definition)
\begin{equation}
\alpha^{\sigma\tau}=\alpha^{\sigma}\alpha^{\tau}\alpha^{-1}.
\end{equation}

[image]

Comment: Do you want to know why $\chi_a$ is a morphism, or why $a\mapsto \chi_a$ is a morphism ?

Comment: Sorry, I'll edit and make it more explicit. I want to know why $\chi_a$ is a homomorphism first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $a\in \Delta$, and choose $\alpha$ such that $\wp(\alpha)=a$. Then by definition of $\wp$ as a $G$-morphism, you have for all $\tau\in G(L|K)$:  $\wp(\tau(\alpha)) = \tau(\wp(\alpha)) = \tau(a) =a = \wp(\alpha)$. So $\wp(\alpha^{\tau-1}) = 1$, ie $\alpha^{\tau-1}\in \mu_\wp\subset K$. In particular, for all $\sigma\in G(L|K)$, $\sigma(\alpha^{\tau-1}) = \alpha^{\tau-1}$.

Now $\sigma(\tau(\alpha)) = \sigma(\alpha^{\tau-1}\alpha) = \alpha^{\tau-1}\sigma(\alpha) = \alpha^{\tau-1}\alpha^{\sigma-1}\alpha$, which gives $\chi_a(\sigma\tau) = \chi_a(\sigma)\chi_a(\tau)$.

Comment: I just realized that I think you meant "So $\wp(\alpha^{\tau-1})=1$. Other than that, it seems correct. Thanks.

Comment: Ah yes of course, good call.

Comment: By the way, I have another 'related' question, and I think it  was more appropriate to create another question topic. If you want to help, I'd appreciate it a lot: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1738033/neukirch-abstract-kummer-theory-understanding-a-proof